# Parsing Jekyll's Categories

Tags: ruby, blogs, jekyll, blog-engine

I have created a simple blog based on the [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) engine but I need one more function to make the thing really complete.

In Jekyll, parent directories of posts are implicitly 'labels' or 'categories'. So, if I were to create a post under the directory structure

```
/computers/scm/git
```

it would end up having 3 labels (computers, scm, git)

In my blog, I have created a few pages:

```
/computers/index.html
/computers/scm/index.html
/computers/scm/git/index.html
```

and these pages explicitly list posts in their respective categories such that /computers/index.html displays links to every post in /computers, /computers/sc and /computers/scm/git ... and likewise on down the road. Unfortunately, categories are not compound in Jekyll and so, "/computers/scm/index.html" iterates over the same set of posts as "/sandwiches/scm/index.html" …

Now, I'd like to automatically generate a sitemap listing all the categories, providing links to all of the pages I've created. Jekyll includes a construct "site.categories" that I can iterate over which works just great for all the top level categories. The problem is that when "scm" comes up, there is no "/scm/index.html" - it needs to be "/computers/scm/index.html".

I'm not sure I can fix this behavior - what type of extensions can I write to get both hierarchical categories and automatically generate a site map to my listing pages?

In my wildest dreams, I'd like to be able to tag a post as /a/b/c and have it associated with labels /a, /a/b and /a/b/c and then be able to generate pages that iterate over exactly these sets of posts. I need the site's organization to drill down from general to specific.

Do I need to try a different static generation engine?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Jekyll's plugins. For categories support in my blog I use one of [this](https://github.com/recurser/jekyll-plugins).

If you are Github Pages user, you must note that GP does not support plugins because of security reasons. To avoid this, you may use ideas from [this](http://charliepark.org/jekyll-with-plugins/) blog post.

---

As an alternative, you can use [Octopress](http://octopress.org/), which is Jekyll-based.